# ASP MVC 5 - Change made in business a layer (project) isn't seen by a site (project)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

everybody.

1. I created an empty solution, added in it the project business logic (BLL) and project site (WEB)
2. Build All
3. In the project the WEB in references i added  BLL.DLL

Now I make changes in BLL but in a WEB I don't see them until I will make Build BLL project

Comment: Add a reference to the project, not to the DLL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a Reference to the **project**, BLL in this case.  Take a look at this [`link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Otherwise, you will only see the changes from the last build you made on the BLL project. Then, when you build your Web Project, it will also build the `BLL.DLL`, so the solution will be up to date.

Change steps to:

1. Create empty solution
2. Add Web Project
3. Add BLL Class library
4. Right click Web Project reference folder, add reference, click Projects tab and select BLL project
5. Build solution, you will see the BLL.DLL in the bin of the web project.

Comment: i make its steps, but in the bin of the web project not exist BLL.DLL  its my refferences in web project http://joxi.ru/_QsOUxjKTJAER9hQlH4

Comment: it doesn't occur, files aren't added

The following are added to your Web project's Bin folder:
A copy of the assembly created from the added project.
Copies of dependent assemblies, XML document files, license files, resource files, and so on.
The program database (.pdb) file, which holds debugging and project state information for the debug version of the added assembly. This file is copied if present in the original location, regardless of the build settings.

Comment: reference the BLL project, build solution, right click the web project, view in windows explorer, and look in the bin dir

Comment: thanks!!! my misteik wos - "click Projects tab and select BLL project". i click browse...  tell me please its correctly use Class library for BLL? in the past I've used another mvc project